# python sqlite3 executemany except for each row

Tags: python, sqlite, except

I want to execute executemany and get exception or suceeded status for each row

```
data = [('H19150', 9677, 519.0, 558.0),#success
 ('345', 9666, 606.4, 651.8),# primary key exception
 ('H19159', 9665, 657.4, 705.0),#unique key exception
 ('H19215', 9678, 528.4, 569.4),#success
 ('6546', 324, 528.4, 569.4),#foreign key exception
 ('H19158', 45, 528.4, 569.4)]#success

import sqlite3
try: conn.executemany('INSERT or IGNORE INTO coated VALUES (?,?,?,?)', data)
except #catch error for each row:
    #what to write here
```

I want to get error for each row
Something like:

```
success
primary key exception
unique key exception
success
foreign key exception
success
```

in one variable after executemany is over.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if you use `executemany()`, then the entire insert will behave as a single succeed/fail transaction.  If you want to get feedback on each tuple, then you should iterate your list and do a separate insert for each tuple:

```
for tuple in data:
    try: conn.execute('INSERT or IGNORE INTO coated VALUES (?)', tuple)
except #catch error for each row:
```